LSP plugins with Audacity on Linux?
I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (to be reinstalled) and I am trying to use LSP plugins. more precisely - the Phase Detector plugin, with Audacity or Ardour. Alternatively, a simple phase meter app recommendation for Linux would be highly appreciated.
However, it is not clear to me if it is possible to use LSP plugins with Audacity and how, also if they could be standalone?
I don't understand the formats very well - JACK, CLAP, VST3, VST2, etc. (It says JACK is standalone?). I followed the installation guide of JACK and VST2/3, but I could not make them run neither standalone (JACK), nor with Audacity, nor with Ardour (errors with VST3 glibc version, which I changed to 2.29 as requested and it didn't help).
I need a manual for beginners on how to install LSP Plugins on either Audacity (preferred), or on Ardour, or on other platform that they are tested to work well. Any suggestions? I need specific steps (the installation guide is quite vague), or phase meter app recommendations.

Hi Mateva. JACK is an "audio connections kit", for routing digital audio. So I think you'd need to have that installed. I have no experience of this btw, and I think you should contact Audacity or even LSP to clarify installation steps for your particular system.
